# Python. SQL Alchemy. Object not bound to a Session. Attribute refresh operation cannot proceed

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Всем привет. Некто не сталкивался с подобным исключением?

> ["Instance Object at 0x7f1101d1e3c8 is not bound to a Session;
>   attribute refresh operation cannot proceed"]

Исключение появляется после выполнения данного куска кода. В частности, в конце его выполнения, при возврате current_request.id

```
        current_request = db_session.query(
            Request
        ).filter(
            Request.id == request_id
        ).one()

        current_request.catalog_request_priority_id = catalog_request_priority.id
        current_request.contact_phone = contact_phone
        current_request.contact_email = contact_email
        current_request.service_id = service.id
        current_request.is_emergency = is_emergency
        current_request.is_paid = is_paid
        current_request.is_planned = is_planned
        db_session.commit()

        current_document = db_session.query(
            Document
        ).filter(
            Document.id == current_request.document_id
        ).one()

        if service.catalog_service_category_id == 2:
            current_document.catalog_document_type_id = 2
        if service.catalog_service_category_id == 3:
            current_document.catalog_document_type_id = 1

            current_document.description = description
            current_document.external_number = external_number
            current_document.modified_by = author_id
            current_document.modified_at = datetime.utcnow()
        db_session.commit()

        if service.catalog_service_category_id not in [2, 3]:
            raise MethodException(
                'Incorrect service category'
            )
        if current_request.is_emergency is True and current_request.sla_id is None:
            current_request.sla_id = 6
        if current_request.is_emergency is False and current_request.sla_id is None:
            current_request.sla_id = 4
            db_session.commit()

        current_request.planned_reaction_time = self.__get_planned_reaction_time(
            sla_id=current_request.sla_id,
            user_session_container=user_session_container
        )
        db_session.commit()
        return current_request.id
```

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобным и может посоветовать решение проблемы, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Догадки.. :)
После

```
    current_request.is_planned = is_planned
    db_session.commit()
```

Все изменения в сессии были закомичены, и связь инстанса модельки с сессией за ненадобностью удалилась

И когда вы в конце кода юзаете

```
    current_request.planned_reaction_time = blabla
```

то в сессии db_session нет объекта current_request и нельзя выяыить грязные изменения которые нужно снести в базу.

Какие я вижу решения:

1. в верху вместо db_session.commit() вызвать db_session.flush() а db_session.commit() вызывать в самом конце и один раз
2. перед вызовом второго коммита снова "взять" экземпляр модельки

   ```
   current_request = db_session.query(
       Request
   ).filter(
       Request.id == request_id
   ).one()
   ```
3. попробовать что-нибудь с session.refresh(current_request) [session.refresh()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_state_management.html#refreshing-expiring)